# Flutter, Firebase Storage Audio Streaming delay

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-storage, streaming

I am a flutter/firebase newbie and am having trouble getting streaming working.

I am getting a 3-4 second delay between executing this following code fragment and the audio actually being played. The audio file is stored in firebase storage. Can anyone tell me what I am missing that causes the long delay or is there some setup within firebase or the audio file itself that needs to be done. The file does play successfully just after 3-4 seconds.

```dart
  void playAudio(String storageFileUrl) async {
      try {
        await warmupAudio.setUrl(storageFileUrl);
        await warmupAudio.setVolume(globals.preferences.voiceVolume);
        await warmupAudio.play();
      } catch (e) {
        print("Error loading audio source: $e");
      }
    }
  }
```

the url I am playing is here:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mindful-f89d8.appspot.com/o/temp%2F_2021-06-08T03%3A31%3A01.994469.m4a?alt=media&token=b8d48358-83a4-478c-905e-caddeb293736

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You're not missing anything. That is the intended behaviour since the file has to be loaded over the network.

Checkout this quote from [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio)'s documentation:

> When the user presses "play" to start a new track, the button will
> immediately reflect the "playing" state change although there will be
> a few moments of silence while the audio is loading (while
> processingState == loading) but once the buffers are finally filled
> (i.e. processingState == ready), audio playback will begin

Comment: Thanks for that. So its just unacceptably slow, will have to look at amazon S3 then for streaming and see if that has better performance. very surprising how slow it is though